# C::B Projet, non necessary files SVN

Tags: c++, svn, codeblocks

I am currently developing a software with some partners. We are using Codeblocks to manage the project, and are likely going to be using SVN as a versioning tool.

However, as I already used SVN to work on a report with latex, I'm aware that some files are completely unnecessary.

My question is therefore a little bit broad. How do you think we should proceed using the SVN repository ?

Should we put the C::B project directory directly inside the SVN repository ? (I assume we will have some problem with the project options, as the library are not in the same place for everyone)
Should we put only the source files in the directory and "link" the source files to a codeblocks project outside the SVN repository ? This solution may allow other IDE to be used with the same source files, right ?

Best regards,

Al_th

Answer (score 0):

i think you shouldnt stick to one IDE. Better solution is to create universal build system like Makefile or Cmake.  With MakeFile you can easy import project to all decent IDE's.( more of them even support to download project from remote repository)

With universal build system you can use it with your own favourite IDE or even compiler.

I would also consider to change C::B to kdevelop it is fully suporrted with SVN/GIT/Cmake/Make. Also there is support for c++11x.

Isnt it more related to programmers than c++ stackoverflow?